# How to number items and write below them without indentation in Latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have a question that maybe it's simple but I can't do by myself. I want to enumerate items (I'm doing with `\begin{enumerate}`) but also, want to write paragraphs below each `\item`. Something like this:

```
The methods are:
   1. Classic
The best for almost all cases. This is very used and it's the easiest option. We recommend you
to use it too over other options
   2. Advanced
The best for advanced users.
```

Something Word-like text. How can I do it? I tried some packages, cmd's but the paragraphs are always indented.

This is my code:

```
...
\begin{enumerate}
    \itemindent=17.87pt
    \item \textbf{Copyrights.}
%Here should be paragraphs without enumerating or indentation.
    \item \textbf{Tools}
\end{enumerate}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to set an `enumerate` with the `wide` option, and additionally push back the paragraph indent by `\labelwidth.` Below I incorporate these settings in a newly-defined `methods` environment, with `\newmethod{<method>}` setting the method title (so it can be easily changed in the future).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{methods}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[methods]{%
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  wide,
  listparindent=-\labelwidth
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\newmethod}{ m }{\item \textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

The method are:
\begin{methods}
  \newmethod{Classic}
  
  The best for almost all cases. This is very used and it's the easiest option. 
  We recommend you to use it too over other options

  \newmethod{Advanced}
  
  The best for advanced users.
\end{methods}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the start value of the `enumeration` counter by using the `setcounter{enumi}{startvalue}` command

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
The methods are:
\begin{enumerate}
    \itemindent=17.87pt
    \item Classic
\end{enumerate}
The best for almost all cases. This is very used and it's the easiest option. We recommend you
to use it too over other options
\begin{enumerate}
  \itemindent=17.87pt
  \setcounter{enumi}{1}
  \item Advanced
\end{enumerate}
The best for advanced users.

\end{document}
```

With the result
[image]